# Why there is an extra name to array stored in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having this code with one parent component (app) and two children (Inputs, List). `Inputs` is for writing data, a callback from parent is saving it to a `people` array which writes that data in `List` component.

My question is, why do it requires `people.people.map(...)` instead of `people.map(...)`? And how can it be fixed that.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Inputs from './components/Inputs';
import List from './components/List';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState({ name: '', email: '' });
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

  const callback = (e) => {
    setPeople((people) => [...people, person]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Inputs callback={callback} person={person} setPerson={setPerson} />
      <List people={people} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Inputs:

```
const Inputs = ({ person, setPerson, callback }) => {
  const updateName = (e) => {
    setPerson((person) => ({ ...person, name: e.target.value }));
  };

  const updateEmail = (e) => {
    setPerson((person) => ({ ...person, email: e.target.value }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>name:</label>
      <input onChange={updateName}></input>
      <label>email:</label>
      <input onChange={updateEmail}></input>
      <button onClick={() => callback(person)}>add person</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Inputs;
```

List:

```
const List = (people) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {people.people.map((p) => ( // <---- HERE
        <div>
          <span>{p.name}</span>
          <span>{p.email}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you name props to `people` in `List` component

You may change like this

```
const List = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.people.map((p) => ( // <---- HERE
        <div>
          <span>{p.name}</span>
          <span>{p.email}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

or this

```
const List = ({people}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {people.map((p) => ( // <---- HERE
        <div>
          <span>{p.name}</span>
          <span>{p.email}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```